# Why can't i run a javascript function from c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a part of the C# code where i want to insert the network graph:

```
DetailsBody3.Text = "<tr class=\"space\">";
DetailsBody3.Text += "<td>" + "<div id=\"center-container\"><div id=\"infovis\"></div>       />";
DetailsBody3.Text += "</div></td>";
DetailsBody3.Text += "</tr>";
```

In the "infovis" div in the graph code, the graph exists.
And in the graph javascript file:

```
function init1(){
  // init data
}
var fd = new $jit.ForceDirected({
    //id of the visualization container
    injectInto: 'infovis',
    // some other code,
}
```

I want to call the int1() function and draw the graph in the table created in C# above.

Comment: What isn't working? What are you trying to do? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code runs in the browser. Your ASP.Net C# code runs in the server.

What you actually want to do is add this to the  section of your your .aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
      function(){
          init();
      }
  );
</script>
```

This will call your javascript init() method once the page has loaded.

Comment: Then you should show us a pastebin of the code you have, and some more information about exactly what's not working.

Comment: shame i can't upvote your comment above more. such good advice. anyway, +1 for the answer too..!!

Comment: This is my first day in Stack Overflow so just give me a day to get used to it

Comment: hanady - sorry for the baptism of fire :-). you'll get used to it and if you formulate your querstions with as much info as possible, you'll get some fantastic answers, plus perhaps even the odd upvote for a well thought out question. keep plugging...

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Page thisPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
if (!thisPage.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("run_init1")) {
    thisPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        thisPage.GetType(),
        "run_init1",
        "init1();",
        true);
}
```

The above may need to be adjusted a bit depending on what version of the .Net Framework you are using (this works with version 4.0).